# Empty post_request_body

Tags: html, nginx, post

I am trying to send a POST request to my server with HTML but when i check access log on my server where nginx is running i only see post_request_body empty ('-') does anyone see where could be a problem? That's how my code looks right now. Thanks for any help.

```
<iframe name="dummyframe" id="dummyframe" style="display: none;"></iframe>

<form action="https://myserver.com" target=dummyframe method="POST">
<div>
  <label for="date">When do you come?</label>
  <input type="date" id="od" value="2020-01-20">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="date">When do you leave?</label>
  <input type="date" id="do" value="2020-01-21">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="text" id="em" value="email">
</div>
<div>
  <button>Send!</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: have you tried giving the name attribute to each input. <input type="date" id="do" name="do" value="2020-01-21">. When you want to access the submitted values you access them with: $_POST['name']. The name being the one you gave to the input as shown before.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It helped, now i see in the browser settings the form data that has been sent. Unfortunately it still does not show in the server acces_log, it shows the post request but the body is still only ('-'). I am not sure how to work with the form data and separate on the server.